# form not submitting text box's new value

Tags: asp.net-mvc, forms, asp.net-mvc-4, http-post

I have a form, whose textboxes are generated via loop and contains its default value. But upon submission, I get its default value and not the value that was just updated.

Here is the `cshtml` code

```
<fieldset>
    <legend>Module <small>Edit</small></legend>
     @using (Html.BeginForm("Edit", "Module"))
    {
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
        @Html.HiddenFor(m=>m.Id)
        for(var i = 0; i < Model.Properties.Count(); i++)
        {
             @Html.HiddenFor(model=>Model.HiddenProperties[i].Value)
            <label class="label">@Model.Properties[i].Name</label>
            <div class="input-block-level">@Html.TextBoxFor(model => Model.Properties[i].Value, new { @value = Model.Properties[i].Value })</div>
        }

         <div class="form-actions">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" id="Submit">Save changes</button>
        @Html.ActionLink("Cancel", "ModuleList", null, new { @class = "btn " })
    </div>

    }
</fieldset>
```

Any idea on what mistake I'm doing?
I'm using hiddenfor so that I can check if user has changed the previous value.

**Edit1:** 
I tried

```
new { Value = Model.Properties[i].Value }
```

and

```
new { @Value = Model.Properties[i].Value }
```

Still didn't work.

**Edit2:**
just realised it shows current value by default, so i removed the new part in textboxfor. Still don't get the updated value in post method of the controller. So now i have

```
<div class="input-block-level">@Html.TextBoxFor(model => Model.Properties[i].Value)</div>
```

**Edit3:** here is the image to make things more clear

[image]

now in following image I try to change the value of `MicrophoneArrayRackModuleId`'s value form **999888** to **99988877** just by typing 77 at the end of current value and i click `save changes` button

[image]

after clicking `save changes` button i get forwarded to `HttpPost` method, and upon inspecting the `module` parameter in the method I see the value that is shown in picture. I was expecting it to be **99988877** but it shows **999888**

[image]

**Edit4:**
On running developers tool from chrome, I checked network->httppost method->Headers->formdata and this is what it shows

```
Id:50
HiddenProperties[0].Value:999888
Properties[0].Value:99988877
HiddenProperties[1].Value:000-00000-000
Properties[1].Value:000-00000-000
HiddenProperties[2].Value:1a2b3c
Properties[2].Value:1a2b3c
```

which is the value i'm expecting in post method of controller but thats not happening.

**Edit5:**
as mentioned by Darin I added name field in view and it now looks like

```
        for(var i = 0; i < Model.Properties.Count(); i++)
        {
            @Html.HiddenFor(model=>model.HiddenProperties[i].Name)
             @Html.HiddenFor(model=>model.HiddenProperties[i].Value)
            <label class="label">@Model.Properties[i].Name</label>
            <div class="input-block-level">@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Properties[i].Value)</div>
        }
```

still it doesn't work

**Edit6:**
**Model**

```
  public class PropertyViewModel
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Value { get; set; }
    }

public class EditModule
{
    public long Id { get; set; }
    public List<PropertyViewModel> Properties { get; set; }
    public List<PropertyViewModel> HiddenProperties
    {
        get { return Properties; }
        set { Properties = value; }
    } 
}
```

**Controller**

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult Edit(long id)
{
    var module = _repository.GetModuleProperties(id);
    return View(module);
}

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Edit(EditModule module)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        { 
             _repository.SaveModuleEdits(module); 
            Information("Module was successfully edited!");
            return RedirectToAction("ModuleList", "Module", new {area = "Hardware"});
        }
        Error("Edit was unsuccessful, if the problem persists please contact Merijn!");
        return RedirectToAction("ModuleList", "Module", new { area = "Hardware" });

    }
```

**Repository**

```
public EditModule GetModuleProperties(long id)
{
    var properties = new EditModule
        {
            Id = id,
            Properties =_dbSis.Modules.Where(t => t.Id == id)
                                      .SelectMany(m => m.PropertyConfiguration.PropertyInstances.Select(i => new PropertyViewModel
                                       {
                                           Name = i.Property.Name,
                                           Value = i.Value
                                       })).ToList()

        };
    return properties;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Write:

```
@Value
```

in place of:

```
@value
```

Answer (score 0):

just leave it like this:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Properties[i].Value)
```

Comment: thats what i've done, as mentioned in edit two. Still doesn't post the changed value, and posts the old value.

Comment: Have you tried: model => model.Properties[i].Value (m instead of M in model)

Comment: i just did and still it doesn't post the new value

Comment: I am lost, i have my code like this: @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Subject) and it is working. I can't help you from the distance, sorry.

Comment: can you see what is actually posting the browser with the firebug or similar

Comment: I just checked developers tool in chrome and i've posted what i found as edit 4

Answer (score 0):

You never sent the Name property, that's why it is always NULL. Make sure you include it as a hidden field:

```
@Html.HiddenFor(model => model.HiddenProperties[i].Name)
```

Also do not capture the `Model` in a closure. Use the `model` variable instead when writing your expressions:

```
@Html.HiddenFor(model => model.HiddenProperties[i].Value)
```

Also you absolutely don't need to be setting the `Value` attribute, that is what the Html helper is for:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Properties[i].Value)
```

Comment: As you mentioned I sent the `Name` property, but the `value` user updates and posts is still not being passed. I have updated my question and in **edit5**, and you can see what i've done. I have name just to show as a label, it really doesn't matter as I've used it for users reference to show what property user is going to edit, what really matters to me is the value that user updates, which is not being passed :(

Comment: In the screenshot you have shown the `Value` property is being correctly set to `999888`. I don't understand what the problem is and what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: First screenshot shows the current value that is being automatically shown when user clicks edit button. In second screenshot I manually changed the value of MicrophoneArrayRackModuleId from 999888 to 99988877(new value I want to set), and upon save changes click in view I'm forwarded to third screenshot where you can see the new value i manually typed and submitted does not appear. What appears is the default value which was shown when user clicks edit button. I hope i made it easier to understand now

Comment: i've also added some info before and in between the screenshots, which will probably make things more clear

Comment: actually I have `@Html.HiddenFor(model => model.HiddenProperties[i].Value)` in order to store old value so that i can check if user has made some change in previous value, if not i will show error message saying there has been no change. So basically `HiddenProperties` will have previous value and `Properties` will have new value

Comment: I see, your code seems fine. Also from what you have shown in your question the correct value is sent to the server: `Properties[0].Value:99988877`. There's no reason you would get the old value unless you have written some custom model binder or there's something else on the server replacing the value.

Comment: I don't have any custom model binder, I have view model just for edit. I'll post my model and method in controller, may be you can give some suggestion then.