# edit form not working, data is being passed to server but not the httpPost method

Tags: asp.net-mvc, forms, asp.net-mvc-4, view, http-post

I had asked question yesterday, which can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17804385/form-not-submitting-text-boxs-new-value) and
based upon the answer I got from asp.net/mvc forum which can be found [here](http://forums.asp.net/t/1924340.aspx/1/10?p=True&t=635102547108455143), I was told to clear my modelstate, as by default my form tends to hold its default value, and not the value I just tried to update. So, I added `Modelstate.Clear()`, which still doesn't work. Can anyone tell me if i'm using the ModelState.Clear() in a wrong place or if I have to change something?

So, here is the problem, I have a edit form which shows its current values in textboxes, when user clicks edit button. If a user wants to edit some current value which is shown in textbox he edits the value in text box and clicks the save changes button. What currently is happening is in my HttpPost method when i check the values that are being passed, I don't get the new value user just provided, rather I get the value that was shown as current value in form.
But when I check in the developer tools in chrome, it shows the new value user just provided as the value that is being passed to server.

Here is my view

```
@using BootstrapSupport
@model AdminPortal.Areas.Hardware.Models.EditModule
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Edit";
    Layout = "~/Views/shared/_BootstrapLayout.basic.cshtml";
}

<fieldset>
    <legend>Module <small>Edit</small></legend>
     @using (Html.BeginForm("Edit", "Module"))
    {
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
        @Html.HiddenFor(m=>m.Id)
        for(var i = 0; i < Model.Properties.Count(); i++)
        {
            @Html.HiddenFor(model=>model.HiddenProperties[i].Name)
             @Html.HiddenFor(model=>model.HiddenProperties[i].Value)
            <label class="label">@Model.Properties[i].Name</label>
            <div class="input-block-level">@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Properties[i].Value)</div>
        }

         <div class="form-actions">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" id="Submit">Save changes</button>
        @Html.ActionLink("Cancel", "ModuleList", null, new { @class = "btn " })
    </div>

    }
</fieldset>
<p>
    @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "ModuleList")
</p>
```

Here is the get and post method in controller

```
        [HttpGet]
        public ActionResult Edit(long id)
        {
            var module = _repository.GetModuleProperties(id);
            ModelState.Clear();
            return View(module);
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Edit(EditModule module)
        {
            ModelState.Clear();
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            { 
                 _repository.SaveModuleEdits(module); 
                Information("Module was successfully edited!");
                return RedirectToAction("ModuleList", "Module", new {area = "Hardware"});
            }
            Error("Edit was unsuccessful, if the problem persists please contact Merijn!");
            return RedirectToAction("ModuleList", "Module", new { area = "Hardware" });

        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is with your model:

```
public class EditModule
{
    public long Id { get; set; }
    public List<PropertyViewModel> Properties { get; set; }
    public List<PropertyViewModel> HiddenProperties
    {
        get { return Properties; }
        set { Properties = value; }
    } 
}
```

You're posting back both `Properties` and `HiddenProperties`, but only changing `Properties`. The modelbinder sets the new values in `Properties` and then sets the values for `HiddenProperties` which in turn sets `Properties` and you've just overwritten your changes.

I'm not sure what exactly you're trying to do with `HiddenProperties`, but it's completely broken as it's currently set up.

**UPDATE: Suggested changes**

**Model**

```
public class EditModule
{
    public long Id { get; set; }
    public List<PropertyViewModel> Properties { get; set; }
}
```

*Removed `HiddenProperties` property*

**Controller Action**

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Edit(long id, EditModule module)
{
    var originalModule = _repository.GetModuleProperties(id);

    // do whatever comparisons you want here with originalModule.Properties / module.Properties 

    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    { 
        _repository.SaveModuleEdits(module); 
        Information("Module was successfully edited!");
        return RedirectToAction("ModuleList", "Module", new {area = "Hardware"});
    }
    Error("Edit was unsuccessful, if the problem persists please contact Merijn!");
    return RedirectToAction("ModuleList", "Module", new { area = "Hardware" });
}
```

*Edit POST version takes the `id` just like the GET version. You use this `id` to lookup the original version of the module from the database and then you can compare original and posted versions of `Properties`.*

**View**

```
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
    @Html.HiddenFor(m=>m.Id)
    for(var i = 0; i < Model.Properties.Count(); i++)
    {
        <label class="label">@Model.Properties[i].Name</label>
        <div class="input-block-level">@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Properties[i].Value)</div>
    }

    <div class="form-actions">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" id="Submit">Save changes</button>
        @Html.ActionLink("Cancel", "ModuleList", null, new { @class = "btn " })
    </div>
}
```

*The `Html.BeginForm()` syntax tells Razor to just use the current page's URL as the action for the form. `HiddenProperties` form fields have been removed.*

Comment: I want `HiddenProperties` to hold current values, so that when user "if edits" a value it'll be saved in `Properties`. Once the form is submitted, I want HiddenProperties to have old values and Properties to have new value, through this i can check if user has made some changes to current value or not. If not i throw error saying nothing has been changed. So HiddenProperties is like a container which holds current value through which i can check if user has made some changes or not

Comment: what changes do i need to make in my model in order to achieve the desired result?

Comment: I'll check it out an let you know what happens